# What are the transcripts at 2:23 and 2:31 in this Tonight Show clip?

Tags: sentence-meaning, listening

What does Chris Evans said at 2:23 and 2:31 in this Tonight Show clip "Chris Evans Is Starting to Speak Like His Toddler Nephew"? [begin here at 2:15](https://youtu.be/OP7H2fMdfqk?t=2m15s)

What I heard are:
2:23 for nature
2:31 You just kinda say (If he said so, then what does it mean?
Does he mean "you just sort of will say that" or "you somehow just say that"?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2:23 *vernacular* (meaning everyday speech)

2:31 *you just kinda say* (*kinda* = *kind of*)

Both *kind of* and *sort of* can mean *["in a way that approximates" (or: "more or less")](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kind+of)*.

That is, the speaker says the phrase, but *not exactly like the kid* (because as an adult he cannot say it *exactly* like the kid, so he says it *more or less* or *in a way that approximates* how the kid does).